# Predecessor function in λI-calculus

Tags: lambda-calculus

The $\lambda_I$-calculus is a restricted version of the usual $\lambda$-calculus.  The set of expressions in this restricted calculus, $\Lambda_I$, can be defined inductively:

1. If $x$ is a variable, then $x \in \Lambda_I$.
2. If $M \in \Lambda_I$ and $x$ is a free variable in $M$, then $(\lambda x.M) \in \Lambda_I$.
3. If $M, N\in\Lambda_I$, then $(MN)\in\Lambda_I$.

The restriction is the added requirement in the abstraction rule (rule $2$) that $x$ be a free variable in $M$.  In particular, in the usual $\lambda$-calculus we have "constant" expressions like $\lambda y.x$; here we do not.  However, with the usual definition of $I=\lambda x.x$, we see that by rule $2$, $I\in \Lambda_I$.

Recall that the Church numerals are usually defined as follows:

- $C_0 := \lambda fx.x = \lambda f.I$
- $C_1 := \lambda fx.fx$
- $C_2 := \lambda fx.f(fx)$
- $C_3 := \lambda fx.f(f(fx))$

and so on, with $C_{n+1} := \lambda fx.f(C_n f x)$.  Clearly $C_n \in \Lambda_I$ for $n>0$, so we can just define $C_n^I=C_n$ for $n>0$.  But $C_0 \not\in \Lambda_I$, so we are forced to use an alternate version:

- $C_0^I := \lambda f x. f I I x$.

A theorem of Kleene says: a partial numeric function is $λ_I$-definable iff it is partial recursive. So there must be a $λ_I$-definable version of the Predecessor function, which satisfies ${\mathsf{Pred}} \;C^I_{n+1} = C^I_n$. Is there a construction of this function?

Comment: I don't know what $\lambda I$ is, but wiki site on Church encoding has predecessor function encoded in untyped lambda, maybe it will help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding

Comment: Can you try to properly format your comment (which essentially defines the set $\Lambda_I$, right?) and add it to your question, rather than in a comment?  This is essential context for getting a good answer to your question.  If you don't know MathJax, do your best and someone may edit the question to help... but we can't edit comments.

Comment: This $\Lambda _I$ is a restricted class of $\Lambda$, defined by $x \epsilon \Lambda _I; M \epsilon \Lambda _I, x \epsilon FV(M) \Rightarrow ( \lambda x.M) \epsilon \Lambda _I; M, N \epsilon \Lambda _I \Rightarrow (MN) \epsilon \Lambda _I. $
$C _0 ^I  = \lambda xy.xIIy$.  The other numerals are just as in $\Lambda$.  $C _0= \lambda fx.x $ is not in $\Lambda _I$. 
Because the Predecessor for church-numeral contains a constant $K= \lambda u.x$ I am not sure whether this Predecessor function is in $\lambda _I$.

Comment: Is $I$ the identity function, the same as $\lambda x.x$?  Or is it a primitive?

Comment: Yes. I=$\lambda$ x.x. I $\epsilon \Lambda _I$.

Comment: I attempted to fill in all the relevant information in the question.  Let me know (or make your own additional corrections) if I got anything wrong.  I don't actually know the answer yet, though :).

Comment: Also I would be interested to know why (or if) that definition for $C_0^I$ makes intuitive sense.  Is there a nice version of the successor function that also works for taking $C_0^I$ to $C_1$?

Comment: Thanks for your editions. $C_0^I$ is not very intuitive to me, but it has the application $c_0^I c_n^I c_m^I = c_n^I II c_m^I = I c_m^I =  c_m^I$. So this approximates $c_0 c_n c_m = (\lambda xy.y) c_n c_m = c_m$.